# JQuery Script reverses output after form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm using the following script to show/hide DIV tags via CSS with the selection of checkboxes in a html form:

```
var $na = jQuery.noConflict(true);
$na(document).ready(function(){
        $na('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
            if($na(this).attr("value")=="one"){
                $na(".one").toggle();
            }
            if($na(this).attr("value")=="two"){
                $na(".two").toggle();
            }
            if($na(this).attr("value")=="three"){
                $na(".three").toggle();
            }
        });
    });
```

My problem is, that after form submit the event is reversed, meaning a checked checkbox hides, while an unchecked one shows the DIV tag.

Do you have any idea how I can fix this? Is there a better event then click or toggle to do this?

Thanks for your help!

Seb

Oh, and all of this is for a wordpress page template....

Comment: Because submitting the form is like erasing a whiteboard. It starts over fresh. It does not magically remember states of dynamic content.

Comment: Yes, but it does remember when you want it to with some php...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the code that does the toggling from the start

```
var $na = jQuery.noConflict(true);
$na(function($){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
        $("." + this.value).toggle(this.checked);
    }).trigger("change");
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CYgQR/1/

Comment: Hi epascarello! I think this script could work. But it checks all the boxes from the start. how can i have them unchecked in the start? Probably easy to do but i'm really new to this... sorry! thx seb

Comment: Ah, change the click to change

Comment: Ah one more problem though! Sry but we are getting there! ;-) The script works perfect with the first checkbox. but when i check two and three, they don't trigger their divs anymore... ideas?

Comment: OK got it. values cannot consist of two words for the script to work. But I can live with that. All good then! Thanks a lot epascarello.

Comment: If it had two words, how would your original code work? It might be ebtter to use a data attriute instead of the value. `<input data-toggle="one"` and than `$("." + $(this).data("toggle")).toggle...`

Comment: I don't know how, but It did. Maybe because I took a detour over predefined CSS classes?!? Anyway, I like your solution it's way simpler. will give the data attribute a shot and report in a minute

Answer (score 0):

[Setting "checked" for a checkbox with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery)

attr is not the right way of getting a checkbox value. Use prop instead.

Comment: Hi Cornelius. Thanks, but unfortunately changing attr to prop didn't help. Script is working but after form submit the effect is still reversed...

Comment: Use else if.console log each event. To do this $na('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(e){ console.log(e);}

Comment: Or how about `.val()`!

Comment: Hi again. I#m pretty new to this and can't get a working script with your line. would you mind posting me the whole script? sry for the trouble!